# Search bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a search-bar that looks like :

[image]

But the following HTML snippet gives a search-bar that looks something like :

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">

   <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
     <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
     </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  </form>

</nav>
```

How could I make the size of search-bar same as that of the button?

Comment: Just Remove `navbar-inverse` from `nav` class.

Comment: @HardyRocks color is not an issue! How could I make the size of search bar same as that of button? So that they look as one entity.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
     <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </span>
     </div>
  </form>
</nav>
```

You need to use Bootstrap's input group class and put your button appropriately inside it.

Comment: They kind of seem to intersect

Comment: Please make sure you're using the appropriate bootstrap css files.
Seem to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/0fzxyusu/

Comment: jsfiddle is fine but I am getting intersecting components as I am running it on my end

Comment: Two probable causes I can think of are:
1) The bootstrap styles are getting overridden by custom css code on your end.
2) You might be using an older version of bootstrap which might not have support for "input-group" (just a thought, really not sure). The fiddle uses the latest v3.3.2.

Comment: I am getting the same with 3.3.2

Comment: Then the most probable cause would be custom css code. It might be helpful to clear your browser cache and try (In Chrome, long press refresh button and select 3rd option).

You can inspect the computed style of the search button on the fiddle and at your end and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any problem See this tutorial http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/search-panel-with-filters